# Excel Copy rows with changes to sheet2 on a new line everytime

Tags: excel, macros

I have a stock list on sheet1 and in column H you can select a quantity to add via a drop down. This then makes calculations on the same row, subtracting from the in stock value. What I need is when a value is selected in column H and a macro button is pressed any rows that have had stock added is copied and pasted into sheet 2 on a new row every time so I end up with all the changes every time stock is added going down sheet2

This is what I have but it keeps over-writing the data every time and only copies the first line that has a value in the H column.

Please could you help

```
For Each i In Range("H10:H150")
       If i.Value > 0 Then
           i.Select
           ActiveCell.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
           Selection.Copy

               Sheets("Record").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial _
                    Paste:=xlPasteValues
           Application.CutCopyMode = False
       End If
   Next i
```

Comment: Did my answer work for you?  If so please mark as correct, by clicking on the grey/green check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.  I will close the question as answered.  If it did not work let me know what did not work and we can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Change everything inside the if statement to this one line:

```
Sheets("Record").Rows(Sheets("Record").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(i.Row).Value
```

Also you want to assign parentage to the first range in the for loop.  So:

```
For Each i In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H10:H150")
   If i.Value > 0 Then
       Sheets("Record").Rows(Sheets("Record").Range("H1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(i.Row).Value
   End If
Next i
```

Comment: Hi Scott,

Unfortunately it does the same as before.
Only populates the top row that has changes and over-writes every time you submit the macro. I have tried playing around with it but it is not having any of it.

Comment: @CHale is there data in Column A?  I would bet it is empty.  I fixed it so it now looks in column H, which should not be empty.  See edit.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response

Comment: The macro is working in respect that it goes to the next available line on "Record" but it only copies and pastes the top row on Sheet1 with changes.

Comment: So if there is more than 1 row with changes it over-writes the on the same row

Comment: oh and yeah Column A was empty.